# getting around the Gem::Package::TooLongFileName issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I am trying to package a rails app as a gem. Part of what I want to put into the gem are the precompiled assets (so the user doesn't have to bother with that). However, `gem build <my_gemspec>` chokes on the super long file names of the digested precompiled files in `public/assets`. Anyone else been through this?

Thanks!

One other note: this isn't a gem that would be used by another application. Rather its a packaging of a standalone rails app. The gem makes it easier for people to use it by simply calling its executable to run.

Comment: Precompiled assets in a gem are not really that useful in reality - in most cases you want to include the gem assets in your own application manifesto so that the assets pipeline reduces it down to a single file for performance. It would simply increase the slug size of applications that use your gem which is not a desirable trait.

Comment: Indeed, according to the official rails docs (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html#separate-assets-precompiling), the recommendation is to define assets for pre-compilation in an initializer.

Comment: I recently filed a issue request at gem to change this stupid limitation. Whoever came up with this really was insane - apparently 155 is the magic number. Or more than 100 characters. But on my linux system, such long file names work FINE; and ruby itself works fine too. It is just gem that puts this totally arbitrary limit in place - it is time to change this, so that this issue is removed completely.

Answer (score 0):

I got around this problem by doing:

```
config.assets.configure do |env|
  env.digest_class = Digest::MD5
end
```

which shortened the asset names enough while still maintaining a digest